# How to check the order of the elements in an array

Tags: java, arrays

How to check the order of the elements in an array ?

Like i have two arrays, and the program must check if all the elements in the first one are in the same order as of second one, BUT it's fine if some elements in between are skipped

Like,

```
String[] expected = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
String[] actual = { "a", "b", "d", "e" };
```

The above one is fine.

But this below one must fail:

```
String[] actual = { "a", "b", "c", "e", "d" };
```

I Have tried the below looks fine but is there a bettwe way:

```
boolean matching = false;
    int e = 0;
    int a = 0;

    // 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
    String[] expected = { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };
    String[] actual = { "a", "b", "d" ,"g","c"};

    while (a < 5) {
        if (actual[a].equals(expected[e])) {
            matching = true;
            if(e<6){
            a++;
            e++;
            }
            else{
                matching = false;
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (e < 6)
                e++;
            else
                break;
            matching = false;
        }
    }

    if (matching)
        System.out.println("seems alright");
    else
        System.out.println("No");
```

Comment: By writing some code.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Show us some code that you have tried?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  I  have the code i have tried so far

Answer (score 0):

Once possible solution.

```
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < expected.length; i++) {
        if (j < actual.length && actual[j].equals(expected[i])) {
            j++;
        }
    }
    if (j < actual.length) {
        //Does not match
    }
```